# SSIS Duplicate primary key, but the key does not exist

Tags: ssis, primary-key

I am debugging a package in SSIS. In the data flow task I have a source and destination and in between with look up component I add some extra columns that will import into the destination. When I execute data flow task, it fails because of "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"

The thing is that the certain primary key is not a duplicate, it doesn`t exist in the destination table. Any idea of this ?

Thanks

Comment: silly question but did you refresh the destination after adding the extra columns? Also, are you redirecting error rows? This is always a good idea when some error like this happens so you can see which rows are causing the problem, that might give you more insight as to what's going on

Comment: Take of the primary key, load the data and look at it and you'll see the primary key appear before your eyes.... unless you have a trigger doing something wierd

Comment: Also, if you can, truncate the destination table and then run it and see if you still get the same problem. (Of course, don't truncate if it's production data :P)

Comment: @James H , Destination has structure so that all of the columns retrieved from source and added with look up transformation can be inserted into. I have error table and I know which row causes the error, but the thing is that the specific primary key of that row does not exist in the destination table , it is not duplicate

Comment: @Len Well is it possible for you to share the `CREATE TABLE` statement and some sample data including the problem row?

Comment: One other thought. In a situation like this, where I would be positive there are no duplicates, I would honestly remove the PK constraint on the table, do the insert, and then query for `...GROUP BY <key column name here> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Thank you guys, in fact yes, there were duplicates in the data to import. I solve this now.

Comment: @Len I am facing a very similar situation like yours. Could you share more information on how did you figure out there were actually duplicate values in the data finally? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this message but the duplicate is not in the table, then the duplicates are on your imported data.  Since your destination table likely contains production data, I would create a new table based on your original table.

Select * Into NewTable From OldTable

Load your data into this new table, which does not have a primary key.

```
Select PrimaryKeyColumn, Count(*) From NewTable Group By PrimaryKeyColumn Order By Count(*) Desc
```

This will show you any duplicate values.